# Raspbian switches off when network connection is removed

Tags: raspbian, ethernet

I have set up my Pi, initially with DHCP and later with a static IP address.

I find that the OS shuts down when I remove the network connection. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been a hardware glitch, working now

Comment: Will you mark this post as solved so that it's no longer listed as Unsolved?